# Bootstrap-Vue throws TypeError in Jest

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Bootstrap-Vue `^2.23.1` with Vuejs and vue/compat `^3.2.45` and my testing library is jest `^29.3.1`.

But when I add the BootstrapVue plugin in my tests I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$bvConfig')
```

I've tried `@vue/test-utils`, `@testing-library/vue` but to no avail.
Its most probably due to BV not having proper Vue 3 support, but is there a workaround to get around this error?

`@vue/test-utils`:

```js
test("component is visible: ", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
        AccountingTable,
        {
            global: { plugins: [pinia, i18n, BootstrapVue] },
        },
    );
    expect(wrapper.isVisible()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

`@testing-library/vue`:

```js
test("component is visible: ", () => {
    const wrapper = render(
        AccountingTable,
        {
            global: { plugins: [pinia, i18n, BootstrapVue] },
        },
    );
    expect(wrapper.isVisible()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

My jest config:

```js
/** @type {import('jest).Config} */
module.exports = {
    preset: "ts-jest",
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",
    testEnvironmentOptions: {
       customExportConditions: ["node", "node-addons"],
    },
    testMatch: ["**/**/*.test.ts"],
    verbose: true,
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$': '<rootDir>/mocks/file.mock.js',
    },
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.vue$": "@vue/vue3-jest",
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This workaround helped me

```
import { BVPlugin } from "bootstrap-vue";

function createWrapper() {
  return shallowMount(App, {
    global: {
        plugins: [BVPlugin]
    }
  });
}
```